# How to connect a tcp socket with ftp server

Tags: python, sockets, ftp

I have an FTP server on address `ftp://192.168.1.14/` and port `21`. I want to make a program in Python to connect to it and download it's files. It is my homework and I have to use `TCP`. My problem statement is

"You are required to implement a simple FTP operation using python-based TCP protocol.
You will have to create an FTP server and client. Then you will have to create a TCP
socket (SOC_SREAM) and establish connection between the server and the client
module you created (programmed).Once the connection is established you are required
to transfer a file (text file you store on server directory) to the client directory."

I was able to do it using `ftplib` but now I want to do it using simple socket tcp. What I have done so far is

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)


s.bind(('ftp://192.168.1.14/', 21))
#also tried s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 21))
```

but I am receiving error which is

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 34, in <module>
    s.bind(('ftp://192.168.1.14/', 21))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Hopefully you can help me. Thanks

### EDIT:

when using `s.bind((socket.gethostname(),21))`

the error message is

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 34, in <module>
    s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 21))
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Comment: 1. the address given must exist on your machine (it can matter if you develop on a system distinct from the target system). 2. The port must not be already in use, and must not be blocket by a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. Since I want to connect to the existing IP Adress, So the method for it is `connect` not `bind`. So correct code would be

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)


s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 21))

print(s)
```